# how to get the center point of a letter?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using this GN setup here:

[image]

result:

[image]

but unfortunately i cannot get the bounds of my different convex hulls...

I tried attribute statistic -> no values
and i tried bounding box -> no values (aka all zero)

So how do i do that?

here the result of the bounding box of my convex hulls in the viewer:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this as follows:

[image]

It seems a bit sophisticated, but I don't think there is a way with less nodes, since `Bounding Box` can't provide values in case of instances.

Only when you convert the instances into geometry you get processable information.

Therefore I choose the "detour" via curves here.

By scaling the height to zero and then applying `Convex Hull`, I get several lines after the realization, which I convert to curves with `Mesh to Curve`.

These curves then only need to be resampled to two points.

By dividing the single segments I get the center point, which I can filter out with `Endpoint Selection`.

The point determined in this way is then the center point of each individual letter.

[image]